# Need to parse the output of linux command

Tags: python, regex

I have the output of the linux command as below:

```
/auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/drt/hash_list/bk20170401/audit-gc.rb:11:{:component=>"Encryption", :params=>"-f /auto/qalogs/branch_team/drt/hash_list/enc_options_rkm_ekm.rb log_level=debug", :script=>"encryption/destroy.rb", :timeout=>10800, :skipcheckconnection=>1, :minlimitver=>"5.3.0.0"}
/auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/drt/hash_list/bk20170401/encryption-audit-gc-part1.rb:11:#{:component=>"Encryption", :params=>"-f /auto/qalogs/branch_team/drt/hash_list/enc_options_rkm_ekm.rb log_level=debug", :script=>"encryption/destroy.rb", :timeout=>10800, :skipcheckconnection=>1, :minlimitver=>"5.3.0.0"}
Binary file /auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/ert/hash_list/.encryption-audit-gc.rb.swp matches
/auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/ert/hash_list/encryption-audit-gc.rb:11:{:component=>"Encryption", :params=>"-f /auto/qalogs/branch_team/drt/hash_list/enc_options_rkm_ekm.rb log_level=debug", :script=>"encryption/destroy.rb", :timeout=>7200, :skipcheckconnection=>1, :minlimitver=>"5.3.0.0"}
```

I need to only filter this hash file :

```
{:component=>"Encryption", :params=>"-f /auto/qalogs/branch_team/drt/hash_list/enc_options_rkm_ekm.rb log_level=debug", :script=>"encryption/destroy.rb", :timeout=>7200, :skipcheckconnection=>1, :minlimitver=>"5.3.0.0"}
```

and write to another file.

I tried the followng:

```
out=subprocess.getoutput('grep -rwn 
/auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/ert/hash_list/ -e '+alist[0]+'')
print ("output of grep  is", out)
pattern=re.compile(r'(/auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/ert/hash_list/.*.rb:\d)
(\:)(\{.*\})',out)
print (pattern.groupobject(0))
```

I get this exception.How to do it?

Comment: You should look at the `re` doc to see how to use it

Comment: Why do you use `subprocess(grep ...`? Why not only using `module re`?

Comment: I think if you can be a little more clear about the input you are going to feed into your regular expression, the strings you want to match, and the groups you want to aquire, someone my be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple `re` problem.

```
import re

command = 'grep -rwn /auto/qalogs/branch_team_5.7/ert/hash_list/ -e ' + alist[0] + ''
filter  = '/auto/qalogs/branch_team/drt/hash_list/enc_options_rkm_ekm.rb'    

log = subprocess.subprocess.getoutput(command)

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for message in log:
        if re.search(filter, message):
            f.write(result)
```

Unfortunetly, I don't have more sample data to really vet it!